# Automatic creation of type hints in MagicMock

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

I want to ensure that the mock object created by MagicMock has the same IDE autocompletion as the spec parameter provided to it.

If you write the following code, you will get IDE autocompletion when you type the bottom two lines.

```py
from typing import cast
from unittest.mock import MagicMock


class A:
    def f(self, a: int) -> int:
        print("f")
        return a


class f(MagicMock):
    def __call__(self, a: int) -> int:
        ...


class TypingMockA:
    f: f


mock = cast(TypingMockA, MagicMock(spec=A))

mock.f(1)
mock.f.assert_called_once()
```

I want to automatically create such a TypingMockA from A.

Alternatively, it would be best if it could be implemented as follows:

```py
mock = AutoTypingMagicMock[A](spec=A)
```

Comment: Yet another use case for the missing [**`Intersection`** type](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/213). Right now, the best you can get is _either_ have the type of the mock be inferred as simply `A` _or_ as a `MagicMock`, but not both. 